# Extracting TD Information with DOMXPath

Tags: php, domxpath

I'm using the following code to get information from a specific table column, but I keep getting the following error:

Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Here is the table column I'm trying to get information from:

```
<td id="billing_address">1099 Somewhere Lane<br /> Some City, IL 60118</td>
```

Here is the CURL script to get the information:

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);     

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($result);

$xp = new DOMXpath($document);
$nodes = $xp->query('//td[@id="billing_address"]');
$node = $nodes->item(0);

$client_info = $node;
echo $client_info;
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks to Lauris, I was able to get the content to display using this:

```
$client_info = $node->nodeValue;
echo $client_info;
```

The problem is that I noticed the line break tags separating the lines are missing when echoed.  What I need is to be able to differentiate the different lines that are separated by the 
 tags.

I figured I would just grab whatever was between the  tags with the id of billing_info, and then use the PHP explode function to parse out the individual lines.  But the 
 tags aren't there for me to do that.

Comment: `echo $document->saveXML($node);`

Comment: Try this: $client_info = $node->textContent. Or this: $client_info = $node->nodeValue.

Comment: That worked, Lauris.  But is there a reason that it is stripping out some of the html when echoed?  There should be a couple of <br /> tags separating the lines but they're not there now.